# My whitelisted IP in .htaccess is not working

Tags: .htaccess

I'm making significant changes to my website today and want to display a maintenance page for everyone except for me. However, it also keeps redirecting me to the maintenance page even though I whitelisted my IP address (which I triple-checked by doing an ipconfig). I'm guessing something is wrong with my code. Here's my .htaccess file in case anyone can help!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.playbank\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.playbank.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
```

Comment: you can also use the `{}` button for code format.

Answer (score 3):

`192.168.1.*` is your LAN network, which is a private network not visible to the rest of the Internet. You need to specify your **external** IP address, given by your ISP. Enter [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) and use that one.

Comment: @Nancy: If vz0's answer was helpful, you should mark it as "accepted", and both of you will get a reputation bonus.  It also helps later visitors see that it solved your problem.

Comment: You should also leave off the `*` at the end as it will break your regular expression and it will never match any IP address.  It should work OK without it.